# Jacobi identity in associative algebra as Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

In page 2 of Hans Samelson's [Notes on Lie Algebras](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Other/Samelson-LieAlg.pdf), the text gives an example of Lie algebra $A_L$.

> Let $A$ be an algebra over $\mathbb{F}$ (a vector space with an associative multiplication $X\cdot Y$). We make $A$ into a Lie algebra $A_L$ (also called $A$ *as Lie algebra*) by defining $[X,Y]=X\cdot Y-Y\cdot X$. The Jacobi identity holds; just "multiply out".

Multiplying out the Jacobi identity and using associativity of $\cdot$, we have

$X\cdot Y\cdot Z-X\cdot Z\cdot Y+Y\cdot Z\cdot X-Y\cdot X\cdot Z+Z\cdot X\cdot Y-Z\cdot Y\cdot X=0$.

Assuming only associativity, I can't see why this holds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Jacobi identity will give the following:

$$[[x,y],z]+[[y,z],x]+[[z,x],y]=\\(xy-yx)z-z(xy-yx)+(yz-zy)x-x(yz-zy)+(zx-xz)y-y(zx-xz)$$

See if you can multiply now, and use associativity to show that the above expression vanishes.

Comment: Oh whoops, in $[X[YZ]]$ I just expanded Jacobi on the inner one, but thought the outer one is just multiplication. Thanks!