# Counter-example of Jacobi identity for antisymmetric bilinear operation

Tags: lie-algebras

For a bilinear, antisymmetric, alternating operator to be a Lie bracket, it must satisfy the Jacobi identity. I assume this is because a bilinear, antisymmetric, alternating operator does not always satisfy the Jacobi identity.

If I consider this operator without Jacobi identity axiom to be defined on a finite dimensional vector space, I have
$$[A_i,A_j]=C_{ij} ^kA_k.$$

I want to find $C_{ij}^k$ such that the Jacobi identity
$$\text{Alt}\left([A_i,[A_j,A_k]]\right)=0$$
is not satisfied.

Although I am quite sure that there must exist such structure coefficient, I cannot find one. Can someone shed some light on this? Or, is it the case that (although I do not think so) antisymmetry is enough to yield Jacobi identity?

Comment: The Jacobi identity is the reflection of the associativity of the group operation. So if you want a bracket without Jacobi identity you need something like a "Lie group" with non-associative multiplication. Non-zero or unit length octonions come to mind, the tangent space at identity should carry such a thing.

Comment: Since it is first time for me to hear that, can you elaborate how I can see that the associativity of the group is reflected in the Lie algebra as the Jacobi identity?

Comment: See [Jacobi identity in associative algebra as Lie algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459222/a-as-lie-algebra-jacobi-identity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the bracket defined on generators by $\{x,y\} = x$ and $\{x,z\}=y$ and $\{y,z\}=0$, the Jacobiator $$\{x,\{y,z\}\}+\{y,\{z,x\}\}+\{z,\{x,y\}\}=\{x,0\}+\{y,-y\}+\{z,x\}=-y$$
is nonzero.

More generally you can expand the Jacobi identity as a system of quadratic equations, e.g. in dimension $3$ for $$\begin{align*}\{x,y\}&=a_1x+a_2y+a_3z,\\\{x,z\}&=b_1x+b_2y+b_3z,\\\{y,z\}&=c_1x+c_2y+c_3z\end{align*}$$
you get the system of equations $$\begin{align*}-a_{2} c_{1} - b_{3} c_{1} + a_{1} c_{2} + b_{1} c_{3}&=0,\\ a_{2} b_{1} - a_{1} b_{2} - b_{3} c_{2} + b_{2} c_{3} &=0,\\ a_{3} b_{1} - a_{1} b_{3} + a_{3} c_{2} - a_{2} c_{3} &=0\end{align*}$$
and it easy to find a *non*-solution; the one above corresponds to $a_1=b_2=1$ and the rest equal to zero.

Comment: Does this mean that using this method, for Lie algebra with $n$ generators, we can always find such non-solutions for the Jacobi identity?

Comment: @Nugi Yes, for $n \geqslant 3$. For instance you can just extend the same example by setting all the other brackets to zero. For $n \leqslant 2$ there are no nontrivial equations (only $0=0$) so there are no non-solutions.